# Issue related to Database Backup and Restore in .Net

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have C#.Net winform application having SQL Server Database in SQLExpress with Windows Authentication.
There is a Option related to Backup and restore batabase. In DBbackup i have provided user to select folder and database will be copy to that folder.
for restore database i have written following line:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, Application.StartupPath + "\\dbSTK.mdf",true);
```

it throws an exception saying dbSTK is already in use. How can i overwrite file that is already in use?

Comment: have you stopped your database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A .mdf file is not a backup file, but the actual data file. You cannot simply copy a running database (or overwrite a running database.) Typically you would have to use `sp_detach_db` to get the file in state that you can copy/archive and `sp_attach_db` (or create database for attach) to restore the db.

If you just made a copy of the running .mdf as a backup, then the odds are pretty good that you won't be able to attach that file.

While the above is the correct method to detach/attach a database, I would suggest actually performing a backup/restore. It doesn't require taking the database offline and is generally a better approach to managing backups.

How to attach a data file in SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx

How to detach a database in SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188031.aspx

How to perform a backup on SQLEXpress: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms186865.aspx

How to restore a backup on SQLExpress: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms186858

Answer (score 1):

Don't backup by just copy the database file. Use the SQL command [BACKUP DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx). Using this, the server does not need to be stopped and the server can clean up internal stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Do not copy the mdf file.
If you want to backup by code, check out this posting
[Using Smo.Backup to backup SQL Server database to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199972/using-smo-backup-to-backup-sql-server-database-to-string/8200019#8200019)

If you want to schedule a backup (to your backup folder) create a new maintenance plan using the maintenance plan wizard in sql management studio:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189036.aspx

Comment: SQL Express doesn't support maintenance plans, but SMO would be a great way to perform a backup/restore in the .net code